# Linking and Compiling C library Undefined symbols. Predeclaration in another file to implementation

Tags: c, makefile, linker, freeimage

Okay so I am experiencing some issues with compiling and linking a C library (LibJXR from Microsoft) with a predeclaration in one file and the implementation in another. (Building FreeImage 3.16 for iOS)

The compiling part is successful, however the linking not so much (however I do believe the issue is in the compiling though).

So this is what I know. I have a file called "decode.c" which has a Predeclaration to a function called `AdaptHighpassDec`, however this is implemented in another c file called `segdec.c`.

Stack of errors when building against lib with a target of i386 (Xcode)

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_AdaptHighpassDec", referenced from:
      _ResetCodingContextDec in freeimage.a(decode.o-i386)
  "_AdaptLowpassDec", referenced from:
      _ResetCodingContextDec in freeimage.a(decode.o-i386)
  "_DecodeMacroblockDC", referenced from:
      _processMacroblockDec in freeimage.a(strdec.o-i386)
      _WMPhotoTranscode in freeimage.a(JXRTranscode.o-i386)
  "_DecodeMacroblockHighpass", referenced from:
      _processMacroblockDec in freeimage.a(strdec.o-i386)
      _WMPhotoTranscode in freeimage.a(JXRTranscode.o-i386)
  "_DecodeMacroblockLowpass", referenced from:
      _processMacroblockDec in freeimage.a(strdec.o-i386)
      _WMPhotoTranscode in freeimage.a(JXRTranscode.o-i386)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

So I believe what is happening is `AdaptHighpassDec` is built into the `strdec.o-i386` object and so when the linker is saying, oh hey there is no `AdaptHighpassDec` in `decode.o-i386` which was declared here. The other errors I believe to be the same problem however with different functions.

So without major source file reworking, is there a way I can resolve this, like compiling the objects into one? Or should I just merge the other c file into the main one and only compile that one all together.

I am using makefile to build the library and a custom script which I can share if helpful

Here is the C Source files for the first problem files:
https://gist.github.com/danoli3/8703453ee7ce7eff7a8a

Comment: Is the function `AdaptHighpassDec` or `_AdaptHighpassDec`? Because those are two different things. Is C++ involved here anywhere? Could this be an `extern C` (or similar) issue?

Comment: Yes the function is called `AdaptHighpassDec`. `_AdaptHighpassDec` does not exist anywhere apart from the compiled libs. I thought it was just prefixing them for some internal reason.

This is compiled at the same time as some other C++ libs, however the compiler for these files is definitely `clang` not `clang++`. It could be an `extern C` issue.

Comment: If you are including the header files for this C library from C++ files/code then you need to have `extern C` around the included C headers (or in them) to prevent the C++ name mangling from being done (and thus breaking the ability to find the C symbols).